# python custom tkinter widgets don't appear in the window

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to create a sample GUI using tkinter with customtkinter module ,but nothing appears in the window.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox 
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("green")

 class App(customtkinter.CTk):
   def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # configure window
    self.title("Tracking System")
    self.geometry("350x500")



    self.resizable(False,False) # to disable the minimize/maximize buttons. 

    self.checkbox_slider_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
    self.switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame, command=lambda: print("switch 1 toggle"))
    self.switch.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.switch.select()
    self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame, text="CTkButton")
    self.button.grid(row=1 , column = 1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

I looked into the customtkinter example:-
https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/examples/complex_example.py

But I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `self.checkbox_slider_frame` to a geometry manager (`pack`, `place`, or `grid`)

```
self.checkbox_slider_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
self.checkbox_slider_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
```